# How to add a user's email to a list when a button is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to Rails, so sorry if this is pretty obvious.
I want the users to click a button (I'm using Devise), and when it is pressed, their email is added onto a list. Also, I want a counter that shows how many people have signed up. How do you do this?

Comment: Also what type of list ? Stored in db? Etc?

Comment: Kindly make your question a little bit clearer

Comment: I haven't tried anything. Like I said, I am really new. I want the list to be stored in the db. @Doon

Comment: So basically, I want people to click a button that adds their user:email to the db. Also, I want a counter on the same page that shows how many people have signed up @Lymuel

Comment: I haven't tried anything @Sim, I wouldn't know hwere to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I am making it is by using a form that has a value of the user's current email. Then it will add it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what list looks like but

To contain user's email, add email column on User model or something. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

```
class AddEmailToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :email, :string
  end
end
```

To show how many people have signed up, use Class method.

```
User.count(:email)
```

It is unclear question honestly, so that if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have email field on your **users** table if you are using devise.

To obtain what you want, create new migration,
type this commands on your command line

```
/> rails g migration create_signed_up_users email:string
/> rake db:migrate
```

Then on your controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def index
      if params[:add_to_signed_up].present?
          user = User.find(params[:id])
          signed = SignedUpUser.new
          signed.add_to_signed_up(user.email)
          @signed_count = SignedUpUser.count
      else
          # you code
      end
   end
end
```

Model

```
class SignedUpUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   def add_to_signed_up(email)
      self.email = email
      self.save
   end
end
```

View

```
<%= link_to "Add to signed up", user_path(id: @user.id, add_to_signed_up: 1) %>
<%= @signed_count %>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! One more question though, sorry. What is the code for the button that adds the people to the list?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tag you can you look at my question above? Thanks a lot by the way, super helpful!

Comment: @SamH, kindly check the check for my answer if it helps you, thanks